# Excel: Referencing a value in a cell in a text box

Tags: excel

So, saw a question just now, that has disappeared while I checked out my solution.

So I understood the question to be how to get a cell's value into the text box and also have it update when it changes.

Assume cell A1 contains 1000, then the text box needs to say something like "1000 from Tax Return" (ok, fiction I know!).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, cell A2 contains 1000, formatted as general.

Then I insert a textbox from the Insert menu.
[image]

While the text box is still "selected", enter "=$A$2" in the formula bar and enter.

[image]

Then click in the text box and type in the rest of the text needed. If the value changes in cell A2, then the number changes in the textbox as well.

[image]

Worth noting that the same "selection" method works for the Chart title and legend boxes which means titles can be taken from the sheet and therefore change as data changes...