# Updating data labels on a scatter plot chart with values in cells works in older Excel 2013 but not in new Office 365 version

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which updates data labels on a scatter plot chart with values in cells. It works in Excel 2013 but not in the latest version (O365).

```vb
If PlotData = True Then
    Set RngX = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 2)
    Set RngY = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 3)
    Set RngLabel = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 1)
    cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Set chtSeries = cht.SeriesCollection(cht.SeriesCollection.Count)
    With chtSeries
        .XValues = RngX
        .Values = RngY
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .MarkerSize = 9
        .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Format.Line.Weight = 1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 9) = True Then
            .HasDataLabels = True
        Else
            .HasDataLabels = False
        End If
        .HasLeaderLines = True
    End With
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 9) = True Then
        With chtSeries.DataLabels
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, CStr("='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & RngLabel.Address), 0
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .ShowCategoryName = False
            .ShowSeriesName = False
            .ShowValue = False
            .ShowRange = True
            If (RngY.Value = Worksheets("HelperSheet").Range("C28").Value And RngY.Value > 0) Or (X = 11 And Range("Coupled") = True) Then
                .Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
            Else
                .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            End If
        End With
    End If
End If
```

The code breaks at the line

```
.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, CStr("='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & RngLabel.Address), 0
```

It produces the error message

> Method InsertChartField of object TextRange2 failed

It then goes on to cause Excel to crash and exit.

Comment: Why not just set the data labels to pick up the information from the cells directly? See this for an idea of the method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70237879/4961700

Comment: I think the problem with the `CStr` part of the expression. Try to delete the single quotation marks.

Comment: @SolarMike - I looked at setting the data labels to pick up their information from the cells directly and it's a pretty good idea that I didn't know about. However, I need to be able to manipulate other properties such as the position of the data label and so I didn't go for that.

Comment: @Blackcat - I tried removing the single quotes from the CStr part of the expression but that didn't work either. In the end, I did find a solution which is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

For information, I ended up replacing the troublesome line entirely with the following line:

`chtSeries.Points(1).DataLabel.Text = Range(CStr("='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & RngLabel.Address)).Value`

as in...

```
        If PlotData = True Then
            Set RngX = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 2)
            Set RngY = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 3)
            Set RngLabel = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 1)
            cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            Set chtSeries = cht.SeriesCollection(cht.SeriesCollection.Count)
            With chtSeries
                .XValues = RngX
                .Values = RngY
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
                .MarkerSize = 9
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
                .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .Format.Line.Weight = 1
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 9) = True Then
                    .HasDataLabels = True
                Else
                    .HasDataLabels = False
                End If
                .HasLeaderLines = True
                chtSeries.Points(1).DataLabel.Text = Range(CStr("='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & RngLabel.Address)).Value
            End With
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 9) = True Then
                With chtSeries.DataLabels
'                   Line removed from here
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .ShowCategoryName = False
etc.
etc.
```